# Table - Vertical header and dynamic number of columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, grid

I am trying to make a table with vertical header and dynamic number of columns. I want to use ASP.NET MVC Razor and `foreach` loop to generate columns.

I have constant number of headers (rows) and dynamic number of columns, which every column has value for every row

What i want to get:

```
Header1 Value1,Value2,Value3
Header2 Value1,Value2,Value3
Header3 Value1,Value2,Value3
```

Model:

```
public class RootViewModel
{
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}
public class Column
{
    public int Header1Value { get; set; } //Value1
    public int Header2Value { get; set; } //Value2
    public int Header3Value { get; set; } //Value3
}
```

I really don't know how to resolve this problem without using 'foreach' for every property.

Comment: class `Column` would need 4 properties, one for each column value, and then all your need is a single `foreach` loop

Comment: I have constant number of headers(rows) and dynamic number of columns, which every column has value for every row

Comment: Then your view model needs a property for the first column and a collection property for the remaining columns e.g `string Name` and `IEnumerable<int> Values` and you then need 2 loops, one to generate the row and 1st column, and an inner loop for the values

Comment: Can you at least confirm the first column is a `string` and the subsequent columns are all typeof `int`?

Comment: Yes, the first column is the name of property, the rest are int values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your view models to represent what you want to display in the view.

```
public class RootViewModel
{
    public List<RowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class RowViewModel
{
    public string Header{ get; set; }
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

so that in the view you can generate the table using

```
@model RootViewModel
<table>
    @foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row.Header</td>
            @foreach(var value in row.Values)
            {
                <td>@value</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```